# Log4j logging to log4j.log instead of specified filename

Tags: java, xml, file-io, log4j

I am very new to log4j, so please be gentle.  But here is what's happening and I don't know why: it's logging correctly to a file, but the filename of the created log seems to be wrong.

Here is my log4j config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%-5p] (%t) [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log/messagecount.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%-5p] (%t) [%c{1}] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>           
 </appender>    

<root>
    <level value="debug"/>      
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="rolling"/> -->
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

It creates a log4j.log file under the log folder instead of a messagecount.log file.
Does that value property not do what I think it does?

This is how I init the logger:

Class level variable:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MessageCount.class );
```

And the init function:

```
private void initLogger() throws IOException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.xml"));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

    logger.info( "----------Logger init-----------" ) ;

 //     logger.debug("Sample debug message");
 //     logger.info("Sample info message");
 //     logger.warn("Sample warn message");
 //     logger.error("Sample error message");
 //     logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");

}
```

The log4j.xml config file is in the root of my src folder.

Thank you

Comment: You don't need that init function. Delete it. Just put `log4j.xml` in your application's classpath (bin or build folder, it won't be found in src folder) and your app will find it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Here's what was happening, and I would like to first thank darioo and dogbane for their answers/comments since they helped me figure it out.

The init function is not needed. And using -Dlog4j.debug=true as a JVM parameter showed me that it was already loading some copy of the xml config file that was located in the bin folder.

So if I get rid of the init function, and place the **correct** config xml in the bin folder, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me.

Try adding `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to your JVM parameters to get more information on what log4j is doing and why it is logging to `log4j.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a copy & paste of your xml file and, for starters, configuring log4j throws an error because this file isn't a valid xml. You forgot to add

```
</log4j:configuration>
```

as the last line. Could have this been the source of your problem?

After fixing this, log4j starts up fine and correctly creates a file named `log/messagecount.log`.

I'm using log4j 1.2.15. If your setup isn't the same, try posting your log4j version and your environment. Also, try naming your file differently, like `log/somelog.log`, or just `somelog.log` so you can see how log4j behaves.

Comment: Whoops! copy-paste error.  Also, I got log4j today, off their website, so it's version 1.2.16

Comment: @Matthew: tried with 1.2.16. Result is the same. Post more info about your environment.

Comment: @Nathan: good point. For new projects I always recommend [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html).

Comment: I tried changing the name to somelog.log and it still created a log called "log4j.log" with the appropriate contents: "[12:55:10,896] (main) INFO  [MessageCount] - ----------Logger init-----------" I will edit my post to show how I call it in my java class.